# Signature capture in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, canvas, windows-phone-8.1, writablebitmap

I'm surprised that I'm unable to find any solution for capturing signature in Windows Phone 8.1. So far I found only one in StackOverflow [here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27254745/user-signature-in-universal-windows-8-1-app) but it complains that WriteableBitmap.DrawLine method isn't available.

Code from the above link:

```
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;

namespace ProofOfConcept.App.Controls
{
    public class SignatureCaptureControl : Canvas
    {
        private WriteableBitmap _writeableBitmap;

        private Point _currentPoint;
        private Point _oldPoint;

        public SignatureCaptureControl()
        {
            _writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(300, 130);
            PointerPressed += SignatureCaptureControl_PointerPressed;
            PointerMoved += SignatureCaptureControl_PointerMoved;
        }

        private void SignatureCaptureControl_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _currentPoint = e.GetCurrentPoint(this).Position;
            _oldPoint = _currentPoint;
        }

        void SignatureCaptureControl_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _currentPoint = e.GetCurrentPoint(this).Position;
            _writeableBitmap.DrawLine((int)_currentPoint.X, (int)_currentPoint.Y, (int)_oldPoint.X, (int)_oldPoint.Y, PenColor);
            this.InvalidateArrange();
            _oldPoint = _currentPoint;
        }

        public void ClearSignature()
        {
            _writeableBitmap.Clear();
        }    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Please don't update your question with the solution. I've rolled back your edit and edited your answer with the code. Please check over to make sure you are happy with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a sample code that does exactly what I was looking for. It does let the user scribble their signature or whatever on the canvas, I'm yet to figure out how to save the image and upload it to a webservice. I'll get to that later. But here is the code to create a drawing pad.

[Link](https://limzhenghong.wordpress.com/2015/06/24/drawing-pad-for-windows-phone-8-1/) to the website where I found the code.

I made it as a UserControl.

This is how I used the UserControl:

```
<Grid x:Name="inkPanel">
    <Controls:SignatureCaptureControl/>
</Grid>
```

UserControl Xaml:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MyApp.Controls.SignatureCaptureControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyApp.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="170"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="60"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Canvas x:Name="inkCanvas" Grid.Row="0">
        <Rectangle x:Name="rect" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="150" Width="360" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Stroke="Black" />
    </Canvas>
    <PasswordBox x:Name="txtPin" Grid.Row="1" Width="360" PlaceholderText="Enter Pin">
    </PasswordBox>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Name="btnAccept" Content="Accept" Click="btnAccept_Click"></Button>
        <Button Name="btnClear" Content="Clear" Click="btnClear_Click"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.UI;

// The User Control item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234236

namespace MyApp.Controls
{
    public sealed partial class SignatureCaptureControl : UserControl
    {
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Path _Current;

        public SignatureCaptureControl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            inkCanvas.PointerPressed += inkCanvas_PointerPressed;
            inkCanvas.PointerMoved += inkCanvas_PointerMoved;
            inkCanvas.PointerReleased += inkCanvas_PointerReleased;
            inkCanvas.PointerExited += inkCanvas_PointerReleased;
        }

        void inkCanvas_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _Current = null;
        }

        void inkCanvas_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var pointer = e.GetCurrentPoint(inkCanvas);
            if (!pointer.Properties.IsLeftButtonPressed || _Current == null)
                return;
            var segments = (_Current.Data as PathGeometry).Figures.First().Segments.First() as PolyLineSegment;
            segments.Points.Add(pointer.Position);
        }

        void inkCanvas_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var pointer = e.GetCurrentPoint(inkCanvas);
            if (!pointer.Properties.IsLeftButtonPressed)
                return;

            _Current = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Path
            {
                Data = new PathGeometry
                {
                    Figures = { new PathFigure { StartPoint = pointer.Position, Segments = { new PolyLineSegment() } } }
                },
                Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
                StrokeThickness = 4d,
            };

            inkCanvas.Children.Add(_Current);
        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            inkCanvas.Children.Clear();
            inkCanvas.Children.Add(rect);
            txtPin.Password = "";
        }

        private void btnAccept_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code sample requires the [WriteableBitmapEx](https://github.com/teichgraf/WriteableBitmapEx/) library, the `DrawLine` method is defined as an extension method in that library.

You can install this package in NuGet package manager.

[image]

Comment: it resolved the issue, DrawLine is available now. Now I need to figure out how to capture the signature and send it to server.